# VirtualBox bridged networking Windows 10 guest / Ubuntu 17.04 Host

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-17.04

I'm trying to setup bridged networking so that my Windows 10 Guest OS is accessible over my LAN.  I'm doing this the standard way by modifying the network settings to be "Bridged Adapter".  As soon as I do this, networking stops working in my Host OS (and it doesn't work in the Guest OS).  These are the relevant lines from /var/log/syslog (edited to remove MAC address):

`Jun  5 13:26:29 MWALLACE-NEW kernel: [ 4101.673479] vboxdrv: 0000000000000000 VMMR0.r0
Jun  5 13:26:29 MWALLACE-NEW kernel: [ 4101.765518] vboxdrv: 0000000000000000 VBoxDDR0.r0
Jun  5 13:26:29 MWALLACE-NEW kernel: [ 4101.837271] VBoxNetFlt: attached to 'enp0s31f6' / <MAC ADDRESS OBSCURED>
Jun  5 13:26:29 MWALLACE-NEW kernel: [ 4101.877938] device enp0s31f6 entered promiscuous mode
Jun  5 13:26:42 MWALLACE-NEW kernel: [ 4114.212375] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down`

I have the following packages installed:
virtualbox 5.1.22-dfsg-0ubuntu1
virtualbox-guest-dkms 5.1.22-dfsg-0ubuntu1

I'm mostly looking for avenues of investigation - really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I need more info to help you...Normally you need to have guest VM turned off and then set to bridged and then turn it ON. Please tell me more what are you trying to achieve and I can help you

Comment: What you described is what I did.  VM is powered off, I set the mode to bridged and as soon as the VM boots, networking stops working on the host OS.  Let me know if there's any other information I can provide that would be helpful.

Comment: Try to change mac address under VM network options and start the machine again...

Comment: I incremented each of the last two bytes in the MAC address by 1 and this produced the same behavior.